# Jqgrid not showing json data with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement jqGrid with codeigniter. I set up everything and it seem to be correct, the grid is showing but is not loading any information. The controller that construct the Json structure print the following:

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":"132","cell":["user1","user1@yahoo.com","1123","22767830","22767830","address"]},{"id":"12222","cell":["user2","user2@gmail.com","212222","8888888","888888","address2"]}]}
```

This means that database is being accessed correctly, and that there is no problem with the creation of the JSON.

But the grid is not displaying this information, so I get the JSON printed and then the grid shows with no information.

Below is the code of the controller:

```
function loadData(){           

        $page = isset($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:1; 
        $limit = isset($_POST['rows'])?$_POST['rows']:10; 
        $sidx = isset($_POST['sidx'])?$_POST['sidx']:'name'; 
        $sord = isset($_POST['sord'])?$_POST['sord']:'';         
        $start = $limit*$page - $limit; 
        $start = ($start<0)?0:$start; 

        $where = ""; 
        $searchField = isset($_POST['searchField']) ? $_POST['searchField'] : false;
        $searchOper = isset($_POST['searchOper']) ? $_POST['searchOper']: false;
        $searchString = isset($_POST['searchString']) ? $_POST['searchString'] : false;

        /**************************/


        //array to translate the search type
        $ops = array(
                'eq'=>'=', //equal
                'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
                'lt'=>'<', //less than
                'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
                'gt'=>'>', //greater than
                'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
                'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
                'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
                'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
                'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
                'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
                'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
                'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
                'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
        );
        function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
                global $ops;
                if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
                if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
                if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
                return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
        }
        $where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
        $searchField = isset($_POST['searchField']) ? $_POST['searchField'] : false;
        $searchOper = isset($_POST['searchOper']) ? $_POST['searchOper']: false;
        $searchString = isset($_POST['searchString']) ? $_POST['searchString'] : false;

/**************************/


        if(!$sidx) 
            $sidx =1;
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results('info'); 
        if( $count > 0 ) {
            $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);    
        } else {
            $total_pages = 0;
        }

        if ($page > $total_pages) 
            $page=$total_pages;

        $query = $this->JqgridSample->getAllData($start,$limit,$sidx,$sord,$where); 
        $responce->page = $page;
        $responce->total = $total_pages;
        $responce->records = $count;
        $i=0;
        foreach($query as $row) {
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row->id;
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->name,$row->email,$row->passport,$row->phone,$row->fax,$row->address);
            $i++;
        }

        //return json_encode($responce);
       echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

Here is the code for the model:

```
function getAllData($start,$limit,$sidx,$sord,$where){

   $this->db->select('id,name,email,passport,phone,fax,address');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
     if($where != NULL)
          $this->db->where($where,NULL,FALSE);
       $this->db->order_by($sidx,$sord);
       $query = $this->db->get('info',$limit,$start);
       return $query->result();
}
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
<body>
 <center>
    <h1>Codeigniter With JQGrid</h1>
<table id="list"></table><!--Grid table-->
<div id="pager"></div>  <!--pagination div-->
</center>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Nacionalidades_controller/loadData',
            mtype : "post",             //Ajax request type. It also could be GET
            datatype: "json",            //supported formats XML, JSON or Arrray
            colNames:['Name','Email','Passport','Phone','Fax','Address'],       //Grid column headings
            colModel:[
                {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, align:"left"},
                {name:'email',index:'email', width:150, align:"left"},
                {name:'passport',index:'passport', width:100, align:"right"},
                {name:'phone',index:'phone', width:100, align:"right"},
                {name:'fax',index:'fax', width:100, align:"right"},
                {name:'address',index:'address', width:100, align:"right"}
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            width: 750,
            //height: 300,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption:"List Of Person"
        }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    });
</script>
```

Somebody know how to solve this?

Comment: Post up the code to your grid and we can have a look at what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I just corrected the post with the comments and the code.

Comment: Is the grid actually calling your loadData controller function? Can you see the call go out from the jqGrid and the returned data in Firebug ?

Comment: Yes, it is calling it, because the loadData function is the one that produces the echo of the JSON (echo json_encode($responce)). The problem is that the JSON is not being loaded in the Grid, it is just printed in the screen.

Comment: But is it being passed on to the client, can you see it via Firebug or Chrome etc? You should see the AJAX call go out and the JSON come back on the client side.

Comment: Hmmm, I just checked the response, and it is the JSON plus the HTML code of the view. I have a non CodeIgniter version of the grid, and the response is just the JSON and it works fine. I guess that this is the problem, but how to remove that HTML code that is contaminating the JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems like it would be easy to find examples of throwing out JSON to a view.

Comment: Do you set something like `$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` or better `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($responce));`? See [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html).

Comment: @Oleg: That made the trick, thanks a lot for your answer, really appreciated, now I can see my grid in Codeigniter!! Also thanks to Mark for his help on this.

Comment: @Oleg: Do you want to answer the question so I can vote you up? I was about to write the answer, but maybe you want to get credit for it.

Comment: @Vito: You are right. Comments will be nor used by searching engine. So to share the solution with other the answer would be correct way. I just posted comment because I don't use CodeIgniter myself, so I was not sure that what I suggested could follow you to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should set `Content-Type` header of the server response and not only place JSON data in the body of the response. One can use

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

for example to do this. Probably event better would be to use

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
             ->set_output(json_encode($re‌​sponce));
```

I'm not CodeIgniter developer, but the look in [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html) of CodeIgniter seems be the reason of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg!! that resolved the problem as it eliminates the HTML code from the response and left only the JSON code. Thanks to Mark also for his help for this issue.